# gethostbyname once failed never success

Tags: c, android-ndk, gethostbyname

When I call gethostbyname in a NDK application without networking, then I turn on wifi switch, and call gethostbyname with the same host again, and it still failed, h_errno = 2.

Why is this and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the returned h_error value, it indicates "TRY_AGAIN". From gethostbyname() man page:

```
     TRY_AGAIN
      A temporary error occurred on an authoritative name server.Try again later.
```

So, try again and see what happens.